# how to deactivate magnifier inside a TextEdit?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-view

With android P when you go to select text for copying, a magnified version of the text appears above it (Figure below).

[image]

How can I deactivate this magnified?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: using any `Magnifier` class? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/magnifier

Comment: you can disable text copy.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I do not want to disable text copy, I just want to disable the magnifier :( I want this because magnifier is buggy. How using any magnifier class can disable the auto magnifier I have in all my EditText ?

Comment: @zeus did you solve this issue?